# Python Random number frequency dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a function generates two random integers in rage 1 to 6. And have a frequency dictionary of the sum of two integer values.

It is for simulating two dice rolling x number of times.

Here is my code and my code:

```
def sim():
    dictionary = {}
    loop_value = 0
    total = 0

    while loop_value < 10:
        num_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        num_2 = random.randint(1, 6)

        total = total + num_1 + num_2

        if value in dictionary:
            dictionary[total] += 1
        else:
            dictionary[total] = 1

        loop_value += 1
        print("Loop value", str(loop_value))
        print(dictionary)
```

This code just adds all the values up. So no every value is unique. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can we see some expected output please?

Comment: `if value in dictionary` is "value" defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = total + num_1 + num_2
```

I don't think you should be adding in `total` here, instead just:

```
total = num_1 + num_2
```

Also replace `value` with `total` as mentioned in the other post

```
if total in dictionary:
    dictionary[total] += 1
else:
    dictionary[total] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

While Martins answer probably fixes your problem, you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#counter-objects) for a bit more flexible approach to counting.

Here's a quick example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6) for x in range(10))
Counter({3: 3, 6: 3, 5: 2, 10: 1, 7: 1})
```

Counters are dictionaries, so you can manipulate them in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
    if value in dictionary:
        dictionary[total] += 1
```

with

```
    if total in dictionary:
        dictionary[total] += 1
```

I'm not sure where you are getting `value` from (it's not defined in your code), but almost certainly it is causing your `else` statement to constantly execute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
def sim(loop_value):
    dictionary = {}
    total = 0

    for i in xrange(loop_value): 
        num_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        num_2 = random.randint(1, 6)

        total += num_1 + num_2

        if total in dictionary:
            dictionary[total] += 1
        else:
            dictionary.setdefault(total, 1)

        total = 0
        print("Loop value", str(loop_value))
        print(dictionary)

>>> sim(5)
>>> ('Loop value', '5')
{4: 1}
('Loop value', '5')
{4: 1, 7: 1}
('Loop value', '5')
{11: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1}
('Loop value', '5')
{8: 1, 11: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1}
('Loop value', '5')
{8: 1, 11: 1, 4: 1, 7: 2}
```